# How to refresh TabHost Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost activity as main activity of my app. This TabHost contains 4 activity. How can I refresh this TabHost (or one of my activity which TabHost includes) by clicking on button in another activity.

**btw. I know how to make button, etc. I only need to know code for refreshing TabHost.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startActivity of that tab and have your code of the activity you want to refresh in onResume() method, that should refresh your tab activity. It is working fine in one of my apps.